# MSO Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

Is there a way to "time bomb" a database in Access 2013, as far as, allow a user to use for so many days, and then does not allow user access after those days? I have a program I am writing in Access 2013, but need to have a secure way to collect a licensing fee at the end of a certain period of time. I searched the net, but no real answer. Much thanks

Comment: Does KeyedAccess from Peter's Software do what you want?

Comment: I don't know. I will have to research it and see. I will check in to it...

Comment: It is what I'm looking for, just didn't know if someone had some sort of sample code to make it work with Access. Thanks HansUp

Comment: This has come up many times in at least 2 online Access forums I used to go to.  The answer is out there.